# How to merge columns in single row in Form Editing of jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Say, I have 5 columns, named (First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth). When I double click on one row, I get one form window showing all columns row-by-row.

What I need is, only Third and Fourth columns show appear in single row and the caption of Fourth column should not appear.

i.e

First 
Second
Third + Fourth 
Fifth.

Possible?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of the current situation?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible.

Comment: @Pathak, I do not have fiddle of this situation. Its what my project demand and can not really post the code here.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Alex, I was expecting answer not this. And why people downvoting this. If you do not have answer then ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved.

Para taken from one of @Oleg's answer.

> You should take in considerations, that the form data will be placed
>   in the  having id like "TblGrid_"+grid_id. The rows of the
>   table has ids like tr_myCol where the name 'myCol' is the value of the
>   name property from the corresponding grid column from colModel. So you
>   can append the  element with new  element with an additional
>   information which you need. Of cause you should probably increase the
>   value of the width property of the form.

Later some where in `beforeShowForm:function(form){}` hide the first child() of row  i.e

```
 beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
    $("#tr_fourth").children('td:first').hide()
    ("#tr_fourth").appendTo($("#tr_third"))
}
```